# Override Logback error output

Tags: java, exception, slf4j, logback, printstacktrace

In my custom exception class I've overridden `toString()`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    final String msg = getLocalizedMessage();

    // base
    String str = getClass().getName() + ": [" + code + "]";

    // message
    if (msg != null)
        str += " " + msg;

    // extra
    if (extra != null) {
        str += '\n' + extra.toString();
    }

    return str;
}
```

(yes, I'm aware I should use `StringBuilder` there)

However, when I log such an exception (via `org.slf4j.Logger.warn(String msg, Throwable err)`) the output is as for vanilla exceptions:

```
webersg.util.service.ServiceError: null
    at webersg.util.service.ServiceTools.decodeException(ServiceTools.java:39) ~[bin/:na]
    at tr.silvercar.rummikub.robot.LobbyConnection.sendRequestTo(LobbyConnection.java:143) ~[bin/:na]
    at tr.silvercar.rummikub.robot.LobbyConnection.sendRequest(LobbyConnection.java:98) ~[bin/:na]
    at tr.silvercar.rummikub.robot.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:32) ~[bin/:na]
    at tr.silvercar.rummikub.robot.RobotController.start(RobotController.java:81) ~[bin/:na]
    at tr.silvercar.rummikub.robot.runners.LocalAltinRobot.main(LocalSilverRobot.java:132) [bin/:na]
```

How can I get my extra data to appear? My log implementation is Logback.

Answer (score 4):

A quick and dirty way is this:
logger.warn("your_message_here \n{}", err.toString());

A better way would be to write your own custom conversion specifier (see [logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) so that the custom error handling is abstracted from your application code, and you can configure it's use through a custom conversion word in your logback.xml.

Here's a simple example that will do what you're after:

```
package com.example.logging;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ClassicConverter;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.IThrowableProxy;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy;

/**
 * Simple exception converter.
 *
 */
public class MyExceptionConverter extends ClassicConverter {
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.Converter#convert(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
        IThrowableProxy itp = event.getThrowableProxy();
        if (itp instanceof ThrowableProxy) {
            ThrowableProxy tp = (ThrowableProxy)itp;
            return tp.getThrowable().toString();
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Then in your logback.xml you'll need to reference it like this:

```
  <conversionRule conversionWord="myCon"
              converterClass="com.example.logging.MyExceptionConverter" />
```

And then use %myCon in an encoder pattern like this:

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{0}: %myCon %nopex%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

Note that adding %nopex stops the usual exception handling

Comment: You should extend from ThrowableHandlingConverter (instead of extending from ClassicConverter). Then you also do not need the %nopex hack. And, in case you want to print out the stack trace, %myCon should go after %n.

Comment: I am getting IThrowableProxy as null for  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException with spring boot

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.Logback.error calls the getMessage method of a exception.
Overriding the method is another way.

```java
@Override
public String getMessage() {
    return toString();
}
```