# SLF4J Logging Exception as JSON or Single-Line String

Tags: json, spring, logging, logback, slf4j

I need to be able to log an Exception as a single record in my logs, which will make it much easier to investigate issues in Kibana / Elasticsearch. From what I can tell from the documentation for slf4j, the Logger interface requires messages to be `Strings`. Is my only option to remove newline characters from the Exception message before passing it to the Logger?

For context, I am using the following:

- .m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.28/slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar
- Java 11
- Sprint Boot version 2.1.8.RELEASE

This is a trimmed down version of my custom exception handler :

```java
import my.error.Error; // custom Error class
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
  private void logError(Error error, Exception ex){
    logger.error(String.format("id: %s, message: %s", error.getId(), ex.getMessage()), ex);
  }

}
```

Initially I had attempted to alter the logging behavior with changes to my `logback.xml` file, within `src/main/java/resources`. Unfortunately, this appears to do nothing, so my assumption now is that the `CustomExceptionHandler` that I am creating is overruling the specification set in the `logback.xml` file. Specifically, the `<pattern>` of the `<encoder>` has been changed based on other research. It's attempting to replace all newline characters.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/gateway.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/gateway/gateway.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 5MB -->
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 10GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 30 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m MULTIEXCEPTION %replace(%xException){'\n','\u2028'}%nopex%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"/>
    </root>

    <springProfile name="local">
        <logger name="my.gateway" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="com.netflix" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="com" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="gov" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="org" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

---

### Links

- [Logback Docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html)
- [SLF4J Docs](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html)
- [SLF4J Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)
- [Combine Logback and SLF4J](http://development.wombatsecurity.com/development/2018/12/20/json-logging-for-spring-boot/)
- [Logback and SLF4J - StructuredArguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430644/how-does-slf4j-support-structured-logging)
- [JSON Logging w/ Logback](https://gquintana.github.io/2017/12/01/Structured-logging-with-SL-FJ-and-Logback.html)
- [Collapse Logs - Multiple Lines into One](https://fabianlee.org/2018/03/09/java-collapsing-multiline-stack-traces-into-a-single-log-event-using-spring-backed-by-logback-or-log4j2/)
- [Apache Log4j Layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)
- [SO : Override Logback 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651119/override-logback-error-output)
- [SO : Override Logback 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067209/logback-controlling-the-formatting-of-exception-stacktraces/23068259)
- [SO : Make Logback Output JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934658/how-to-write-slf4j-over-logback-logs-as-json)
- [Format SLF4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054154/logger-format-and-throwable-slf4j-arguments)
- [Collapse multi-line logs into one with Logback or Log4j2](https://prog.world/java-collapse-multi-line-logs-into-a-single-line-log-using-spirng-and-logback-or-log4j2-logger/)
- [Baeldung Log4j2 JSON Logging](https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output)
- [Java Logging Guide](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/java-logging-guide/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my logError method to this:

```java
import org.slf4j.MDC; // new import to add property
// ... other imports from before

  private void logError(Error error, Exception exception){
    MDC.put("error id", error.getId().toString()); // add a new property to the thread context
    LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
    MDC.clear(); // remove all new properties after logging the error
  }
```

My new pom.xml File Dependencies:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
      <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other dependencies -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- ... -->
  </dependencies>
```

New logback.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="FILE-ROLLING">
    <!-- Old encoder is removed: 
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    -->
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/data.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/data/data.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
      </fileNamePattern>
      <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
      <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
      <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, it will delete old archived file -->
      <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
      <!-- 60 days to keep -->
      <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <!-- TODO : configure a pretty printer -->
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
      <provider class="net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.ArgumentsJsonProvider"/>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- TODO : configure a pretty printer -->
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
      <provider class="net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.ArgumentsJsonProvider"/>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <!-- The base logback configuration is removed, but note that this will also remove the default Spring start-up messages, so those need to be added back into the <root> 
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
  -->
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> <!-- This adds Spring start-up messages back into the logs -->
  </root>
  <springProfile name="local">
    <logger additivity="false" level="TRACE" name="org.springframework.web">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="dev">
    <logger additivity="false" level="DEBUG" name="org.springframework">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="prod">
    <logger additivity="false" level="DEBUG" name="my.app.path">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>
    <logger additivity="false" level="DEBUG" name="org.jooq">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>
    <logger additivity="false" level="DEBUG" name="org.springframework">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

[SLF4J Docs - Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html)
[Baeldung Example - MDC + Log4J2](https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback)